# USB works once but disappears when you click on file

Tags: usb

I just installed 17.10 on a system that I built. It has and MSI 970 Gaming MB and I have an internal USB hub connected to the MB by the 20 pin USB expansion connector.  When I put a USB stick in the hub it takes quite a while to display the files on it.  When I click on a file it all goes away never to return.  I am a noob but a retired programmer (IBM, Windows) that is just trying to learn Linux.  Thank you.

Comment: Plug in the usb drive, wait until it appears, click on it and run `dmesg | tail -n 50` and include the lines starting with where you plug in your USB drive in your post.

Comment: This^^^ please, so we can have a better picture of what's going on under the bonnet/hood. Just guessing: Power issues. Many internal or external hubs do need additional power.

Comment: I found the answer...it involves editing the grub file line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to read GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft" and then updating grub with sudo update-grub. Then you restart the computer.  Got a lot of learning to do.  Thank you for replying.